# asus P8P67 PRO montherboard - does not start

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I tried to find similar problems, but seems mine is a bit different. All was fine for long time. When my PC was in hibernation - power in my house went off. Now power is restored, but my PC dos not start. when I press power button, lights on motherboard go on (3 green and 12 red), fan starts, all familiar sounds of it starting - but then - nothing. I wait for the usual single beep, logo on screen - but nothing. No boot up,  not even the logo on screen, in fact screen goes to standby like computer is off.
motherboard is asus P8P67 PRO. power supply is LSP Ultra 750 APX.
I disconnected all drives, removed memory, did reset CMOS - nothing.

Is there anything else I can do or try? or the mobo is fried for some reason?

I  live in Dominica, far from any service center. We just had the terrible storm (this is why power went off).  Computer was off for 3 days. But it was off for much longer when I was travelling. So, I can't find any clue about it - but it is not easy to just send the computer for service.

If you can suggest anything it would be most appreciated. 
I am already delayed supplying work to my client because of the storm. and now - this! Thank you!
Derek

Comment: Check the onboard leds meanings on p2-19 of your motherboard manual. It will tell you what part of the motherboard is not working.

Comment: Thanks so much! seems you helped me with a single shot! LEDs pointed to problem with RAM. I removed all ram and installed back only a single piece for now. and - it boots fine. and red light next to ram disappeared.  so looks like one of ram pieces is fried.
Big thanks once again!!!

Comment: The power surge could of easily damaged your RAM. If you do not have a surge protector for your computer, I would recommend getting one. It won't protect you from all surges, like lightning strikes and other things. But for when the power goes out like that, a surge protector has a good chance of preventing damage to your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Lights on motherboard go on (3 green and 12 red)

Check the onboard leds meanings on p2-19 of your motherboard manual. It will tell you what part of the motherboard is not working.

---

#### POST State LEDs

> The POST State LEDs of CPU, DRAM, VGA card, and HDD indicate key components
>   status during POST (Power-on Self Test). If an error is found , the LED next to the
>   error device will continue lighting until the problem is solved. This user-friendly design
>   provides an intuitional way to locate the root problem within a second.
>
> [image]

Source [Asus-P8P67 Motherboard Manual](https://www.pugetsystems.com/files/1952/parts/Motherboard/Asus-P8P67-Pro-REV-3-0-7484/e6308_P8P67_PRO.pdf)